# WAS 7.0 Adding User to Administrative Role using WSADMIN

Tags: websphere, user-roles

I am unable to grant a user to ISC Admin or Administrator role in the ISC portal, how do i grant an LDAP user administrator role in ISC without using the ISC portal?

Reason being because the ISC portal, after I click "OK" to process, there is nothing happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you add users to an administrative role, such as Administrator role or iscadmin role (taken from http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rxml_7libsecurity.html):

**Syntax**

```
AdminAuthorizations.mapUsersToAdminRole(authGroupName, adminRole, userIDs)
```

**Example usage**

```
AdminAuthorizations.mapUsersToAdminRole("myAuthGroup", "administrator", "user01 user02 user03")
```

Also have a look at the links in the InfoCenter as they will help you with all the related tasks as this will help you with all related wsadmin commands.

- [AuthorizationGroupCommands command group for the AdminTask object](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rxml_atauthorizationgroup.html)
- [Authorization group configuration scripts](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rxml_atauthorizationgroup.html)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for this (like me) in WAS9 ND - the method has changed slightly.

Now it's been documented in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_atauthorizationgroup.html and it's not in the AdminAuthorizations object anymore, but in the AdminTask object like that:

```
AdminTask.mapUsersToAdminRole('[-authorizationGroupName groupName -roleName administrator -userids user1]')
```